# Json.net fails to deserialize a list of complex types

Tags: wcf, json.net, wcf-rest

I'm using json.net to perform handle my json deserialization in a IIS hosted restful service.

First, here are the objects I'm trying to work with.

```
[DataContract]
public class CreateSamplesRequest
{
    [DataMember] public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public SampleTemplateDTO Template { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class SampleTemplateDTO
{
    [DataMember] public int NumberOfSamples { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public int SampleTypeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public HmisDTO Hmis { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public List<AttributeValueDTO> AttributeValues { get; set; }   
}
[DataContract]
public class AttributeValueDTO
{
    [DataMember] public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Value { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class HmisDTO
{
    [DataMember] public string Health { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Flammability { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Reactivity { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string Equipment { get; set; }
}
```

The help page asks for json in this format for the CreateSamplesRequest

```
{
 "SessionId":"1627aea5-8e0a-4371-9022-9b504344e724",
 "Template":{
    "NumberOfSamples":2147483647,
    "CompanyId":2147483647,
    "SampleTypeId":2147483647,
    "Hmis":{
        "Health":"String content",
        "Flammability":"String content",
        "Reactivity":"String content",
        "Equipment":"String content"
    },
    "AttributeValues":[{
        "AttributeId":2147483647,
        "AttributeName":"String content",
        "Value":"String content"
    }]
  }
}
```

And this is what I'm actually sending:

```
{
 "SessionId":"17aaec11-be28-4536-b5df-d98fbda91e91",
 "Template":{
    "NumberOfSamples":1,
    "CompanyId":1,
    "SampleTypeId":9,
    "Hmis":{
        "Health":"2",
        "Flammability":"0",
        "Reactivity":"0",
        "Equipment":"E",
    },
   "AttributeValues":[
      {"AttributeId":1,"AttributeName":"Item No.","Value":"MN0002NG"},
      {"AttributeId":2,"AttributeName":"Lot No.","Value":"C4526"}
    ]
 }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the AttributeValues property of the SampleTemplateDTO object always ends up being ignored. With the above code, it will be null. If I instanciate it to a empty `List<AttributeValueDTO>` it will be an empty list. I've been banging my head against this for a few hours.

I've tried creating a service that just takes a `List<AttributeValueDTO>` and it works fine. I've tried creating a wrapper class for the AttributeValues and it still ends up as null. I'm completely stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MOTHER OF GOD, I JUST WASTED 5 FREAKING HOURS ON A FREAKING COMMA. The trailing comma in the HMIS section was apparently telling json.net to stop parsing at that point.

When I submit this json:

```
{
 "SessionId":"17aaec11-be28-4536-b5df-d98fbda91e91",
 "Template":{
  "NumberOfSamples":1,
  "CompanyId":1,
  "SampleTypeId":9,
  "Hmis":{
    "Health":"2",
    "Flammability":"0",
    "Reactivity":"0",
    "Equipment":"E"
  },    
  "AttributeValues":[
   {"AttributeId":1,"AttributeName":"Item No.","Value":"MN0002NG"},
   {"AttributeId":2,"AttributeName":"Lot No.","Value":"C4526"}
  ]     
 }
}
```

Everything works great.